# Azure CosmosDb: Fresh read item and restore by ReplaceItemAsync() says 404

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Simple process: I am getting items from my container and iterate them. Change a property and store it again.

Method to get items

```
public async Task<ActionItem[]> GetActionsNotExecutedAsync(string transferId)
{
    QueryDefinition query = new("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.TransferId = @transferId AND c.Executed = @executed");
    query.WithParameter("@transferId", transferId);
    query.WithParameter("@executed", false);
    QueryRequestOptions opts = new QueryRequestOptions();
    opts.PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(transferId);
    opts.MaxItemCount = -1;

    List<ActionItem> actions = new();
    using FeedIterator<ActionItem> feed = _action.GetItemQueryIterator<ActionItem>(query);
    while (feed.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach (ActionItem action in await feed.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            actions.Add(action);
        }
    }
    return actions.ToArray();
}
```

Method to update an item

```
public async Task UpdateActionAsync(ActionItem item)
{
    //await _transfer.UpsertItemAsync<ActionItem>(item, new PartitionKey(item.TransferId));
    await _transfer.ReplaceItemAsync<ActionItem>(item, item.id);
}
```

Code that uses both Methods

```
ActionItem[] actions = await db.GetActionsNotExecutedAsync(evt.TransferId);

foreach (ActionItem action in actions)
{
    action.Executed = true;
    await db.UpdateActionAsync(action);
}
```

I expect to see the property "Executed" to be changed to TRUE, but instead I get 404 when using ReplaceItemAsync(). No error but also no change of property when using UpsertItemAsync().

Comment: Does your `ActionItem` have `id`? Also, you're not passing a partition key value (you should be passing 3 parameters, not 2).

Comment: Yes, the `ActionItem` has a filled `id`-field. I also tried to add the TransferId in the 3rd parameter like this: `await _transfer.ReplaceItemAsync<ActionItem>(item, item.id, new PartitionKey(item.TransferId));` ...and sadly it fails the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, i am so blind! I was using different containers *shameonme*

As you can see the first method to read the ActionItems uses a container named "_action" and the second method to update the ActionItem uses a container named "_transfer".